# C++ | Русский язык из Cin НЕ равен Русскому языку из Const

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, консоль

Всем привет!
Недавно начал программировать на C++. Хотел сделать свой первый проект - переводчик с использованием API. Однако, у меня сразу же возникала одна весомая проблема. Русский язык вводимый через консоль с помощью функции Cin **НЕ равен** переменной-константе типы String. Возможно ли это исправить **не изменяя условие в if и константу**? Т.к. использовать функцию `cpr::util::urlEncode()` просто не возможно вместе с Cin...

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    const std::string text = "Привет";
    std::string textFromCin;
    std::cin >> textFromCin; //Вводим "Привет"
    // Проверка
    std::cout << "Текст одинаковый? ";
    if (text == textFromCin) {
        std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "False" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Пробывал SetConsole, setlocale, а также измнения шрифта в консоле. Результат нулевой.

Comment: ¿А файл в какой кодировке сохранен? А еще у функций WinAPI следует проверять возвращаемое значение.

Comment: Кодировка C++ файла - UTF8. Устанавливал её в CMakeLists.txt
add_compile_options("$<$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")
add_compile_options("$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/utf-8>")

Comment: Проверил файл с помощью Notepad++. Кодировка UTF-8-BOM

Comment: Лучше сразу переходите на linux

Comment: Как будто на Linux таких проблем не будет...

Comment: Я тут заметил, что что-то поломали https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-setmode-o-u8text-on-filenostdin-crashes-program-w/1563212

Comment: @avp Ну хотя бы не посоветовали язык менять :) Например, русский на английский.

Comment: @Egor, таких не будет. Кстати, вы еще наверняка не обнаружили, что хотя ввод с клавиатуры из консоли идет в cp-866, передавемые с нее же аргументы командной строки кодируются в cp-1251 (!!!). И подобной галиматьи в этой ОС немеряно.